# JAXB Marshaller does not have elements whos value is null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

When I marshall a java object using JAXB Marshaller, the marshaller does not create empty elements for null files in the java object. For example, I have a following java object:

```
public class PersonTraining {

    @XmlElement(name = "Val1", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal val1;
    @XmlElement(name = "Val2", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected BigDecimal val2;
    @XmlElement(name = "Val3", required = true, nillable = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar val3;
}
```

When I take an instance of this object, and marshall into an XML, I get the following (This is beacuse I did not set the value for Val2):

```
<PersonTraining>
      <Val1>1</Val1>
       <Val3>2010-01-01T00:00:00.0-05:00</Val3>
 </PersonTraining>
```

However, I had expected hte following result from the marshalling operation (Infact, I specifically need  element as well so that the XML can be validated against the XSD)

```
<PersonTraining>
      <Val1>1</Val1>
      <Val2></Val2>
       <Val3>2010-01-01T00:00:00.0-05:00</Val3>
 </PersonTraining>
```

Please let me know what option I would need to set so that the null value in the object attributes can ALSO be marshalled, and returned as empty/null elements.

Here is the marshalling code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("person_training");   
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(ptl, sw);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will not marshal an attribute/element for null values.  This will be true for the following field in your Java model.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Val1", required = true)
protected BigDecimal val1;
```

You can override this behaviour by specifying `nillable=true` on the `@XmlElement` annotation like you have done here:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Val2", required = true, nillable = true)
protected BigDecimal val2;
```

This will cause the `xsi:nil="true"` attribute to be leverage:

```
<Val2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

For more information:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

---

### Java Model

**PersonTraining**

Since you are annotating the `fields` you should make sure you specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` at the class or package level (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PersonTraining {

    @XmlElement(name = "Val1", required = true)
    protected BigDecimal val1;
    @XmlElement(name = "Val2", required = true, nillable = true)
    protected BigDecimal val2;
    @XmlElement(name = "Val3", required = true, nillable = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar val3;

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(PersonTraining.class);

        PersonTraining pt = new PersonTraining();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(pt, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<personTraining>
    <Val2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <Val3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</personTraining>
```

Comment: Can we have simply  <personTraining>
    <Val2></Val2>
    <Val3></Val3>
</personTraining>

Comment: @RahulAgrawal - Empty elements are not a valid representation of null.  If in your XML schema if you define a simple element as a non-string type then validation will fail when the element is empty.