# List Not Appearing In Jersey JSON Response When Null

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I'm using Jersey v1.19 as REST framework.

Below is an Xml-Annotated class for a Response.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Data {
   private boolean hasErrors; // always appears because primitive
   private List<String> remainingJobs;    
   // getter and setter
}
```

The problem here is that when `remainingJobs` is `null` or empty, then it is not included in the JSON response! Example of the response: `{"hasErrors": false}`

I would like to make it appear in the JSON response that's all.  Example of the response I would like to see: `{"hasErrors": false, "remainingJobs": null}` or `"null"`

However, I found out that if I annotate this data member as

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "remainingJobs")
@XmlElement(name = "remainingJob")
private List<String> remainingJobs;
```

Then it shows the `null`. However, the response will be verbose and not pretty when there are actual data. Example:

```
 {"remainingJobs": {"remainingJob": ["J22", "K01"]}, "hasErrors": false}
```

What I would like:

```
 {"remainingJobs": ["J22", "K01"], "hasErrors": false}
```

Another issue is that when `remainingJobs` is empty (NOT `null`) then it is showing as `null`!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983687/jaxb-marshaller-does-not-have-elements-whos-value-is-null

Comment: @Sampada I just tried the solution of that question and no it didn't work for me. Seems like a Jersey problem rather than JAXB Marshaller problem

Comment: try using Jackson or Gson for java-json mapping. jaxb is primarily for XML-java

Comment: If you use Jackson you can add    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS) for Data entity to achive this.

Or you can set serialization inclusion to object mapper for entire application.
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)

Comment: @kartheekvanapalli I did that and it fixed the issue but created another! Now all the fields show! but I don't want that! I want it only for this field!

Comment: @rz3r0 Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields to do field level serialization