# Marshall Empty fields JaxbDataFormat

Tags: xml, jaxb, apache-camel, marshalling

I am currently marshaling populated xjc classes to an xml file/string using jaxbDataFormat. However only populated fields are printing when I marshal. For example lets say version015v003 has 2 String fields, field1 and field2. I set field1 ="something" but dont set field2. I still want the generated xml to have both field1 and field2. As shown below. Any advice on how to achieve this?

```
<field1>something</field1>
<field2></field2>

JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat =  new JaxbDataFormat("com.ups.brokerage.model.boss.version015v003");

from("direct:convertToEntryPacket")
        .routeId("BasXmlTranslation.mapToEntryPacket")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
        .bean("logging", "info(*, 'About to convert to entry packet')")
        .bean(entryPacketToBasMapper, "mapEntryPacketToBas(*)")
        .marshal(jaxbDataFormat)
        .bean("logging", "info(*, 'TRANSFORM: entry packet made... Message Body: ${body}')")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(200))
        .convertBodyTo(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Convert null field to empty string (null -> "")

The workaround will make the field appear, but may result as `<field2/>`

For pure jaxb way, you may check other SO answer for [default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12042095/3759505) or [null field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18984458/3759505).